# How to ensure that user stays in session even after he/she kill the application?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to ensure that user stays in session after logging in, even after user kills the application. The user will only be able to end the session if he/she logs out.

Login.java`

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
Button loginButton, registerButton;
UserSessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //User Session Manager
    session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void OnLogin(View view){
    String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, email, password);
    UserSessionManager userSessionManager = new UserSessionManager(this);
    userSessionManager.createUserLoginSession(type, email);
}
public void OpenReg(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//User Session Manager
UserSessionManager session;

Button btnLogout;

private static ImageButton profile_button1;
private static TextView profile_button2;
private static ImageButton link_button1;
private static TextView link_button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();

    //Session class instance
    session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    TextView loginEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    TextView loginPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

    //Logout
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //check user login
    if (session.checkLogin())
        finish();

    //get user data
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    //get email
    String email = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            session.logoutUser();
        }
    });
}

public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    profile_button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ProfileButton);
    profile_button2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Profile);
    link_button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.LinkButton);
    link_button2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);

        profile_button1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.imedimate.imedimate.Profile");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
        profile_button2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.imedimate.imedimate.Profile");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
        link_button1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.imedimate.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
        link_button2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.imedimate.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

UserSessionManager.java

```
public class UserSessionManager {

//Shared preferences reference
SharedPreferences pref;

//Editor reference for shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

//Context
Context _context;

//shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

//sharedpref file name
private static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";


//All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

//email
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

//constructor
public UserSessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

//create login session
public void createUserLoginSession(String name, String email){
    //store login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

    //store email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    //commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * check login method will check user status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else do anything
 */
public boolean checkLogin(){
//check login status
if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()){
    //user is not logged in, redirected to login
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);

    //closing all activities from stack
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //add new flag to start new activity
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //staring login activity
    _context.startActivity(i);

    return true;
}
return false;
}
/**
 * Get stored session data
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    //Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //user name
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    //return email
    return user;
}
/**
 * Clear session details
 */
public void logoutUser(){
    //clearing all user data from shared preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    //After logout redirecr user to login
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);

    //close all activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //add new flag to start new activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //staring login
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

//check for login
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

BackgroundWorker.java

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://imedimate.com/app/login.php";
    String register_url = "http://imedimate.com/app/register.php";
    if (type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String email = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (type.equals("register")){
        try {
            String regEmail = params[1];
            String regPassword = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regPassword,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    if (result.contains("success")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

The best that you can do is make sure that after the application gets killed, a (sticky) `Service` gets created as soon as possible, which can setup a new session. The situation gets more complicated if you need some sort of authentication from the app's user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store user session token in preference on login success
2. In launcher activity check for session token. If token exists then launch main screen(home screen).
3. Delete token from preferences on logout.